# Call to a member function prepare() on null at CRUD system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using a CRUD system in a web site.
I show a table with all existing records (avisos.php).
When the user clicks on the ADD NEW RECORD button, following script is launched:

```
$("#btn-add").click(function(){
        $(".content-loader").fadeOut('slow', function()
        {
            $(".content-loader").fadeIn('slow');
            $(".content-loader").load('nuevo_aviso.php');
            $("#btn-add").hide();
            $("#btn-view").show();
        });
    });
```

nuevo_aviso.php includes a HTML form to add a new record. This is its content:

```
    <div id="dis">
    <!-- here message will be displayed -->
    </div>


     <form method='post' id='emp-SaveForm' action="#">

    <table class='table table-bordered'>

        <tr>
            <td>Titulo</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='titulo_anuncio' class='form-control' placeholder='EX : P.M.I. DUCTO DE JUAREZ' required /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Texto</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='texto_anuncio' class='form-control' placeholder='EX : Mantenimiento preventivo el dia 17 de agosto' required></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-save" id="btn-save">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Guardar Aviso/Anuncio
            </button>  
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

From here a JS file (crud.js) called from avisos.php should pass the form data to create_aviso.php:
this is the function at crud.js:

```
/* Data Insert Starts Here */
    $(document).on('submit', '#emp-SaveForm', function() {

       $.post("create_aviso.php", $(this).serialize())
        .done(function(data){
            $("#dis").fadeOut();
            $("#dis").fadeIn('slow', function(){
                 $("#dis").html('<div class="alert alert-info">'+data+'</div>');
                 $("#emp-SaveForm")[0].reset();
             });    
         });   
         return false;
    });
```

And then, at create_aviso.php the received data should be inserted in the database:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';


    if($_POST)
    {
        $titulo_anuncio = $_POST['titulo_anuncio'];
        $texto_anuncio = $_POST['texto_anuncio'];

        try{

            $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO tbAnuncios(titulo_anuncio,texto_anuncio) VALUES(:etitulo, :etexto)");
            $stmt->bindParam(":etitulo", $titulo_anuncio);
            $stmt->bindParam(":etexto", $texto_anuncio);

            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                echo "Registro añadido";
            }
            else{
                echo "Error";
            }   
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

?>
```

The problem is that at line 12 from create_aviso.php the browser throws an error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /../create_aviso.php on line 12. THis is line 12:

```
$stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO tbAnuncios(titulo_anuncio,texto_anuncio) VALUES(:etitulo, :etexto)");
```

I have checked the data and found that only the value from `$_POST['titulo_anuncio']` is given to `create_aviso.php`. 
`$_POST['texto_anuncio']` is not received. That should be the reason for the exception, but I don't find the error at the code.

Comment: I don't recomend use global vars, but in your case, try use in line 11 `global $db_con`

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Double check `$(this).serialize()` because it appears the 'this' refers to the `$.post` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of `dbconfig.php` is missing, but I think your problem it's because `$db_con` must be acessible in line `12`.

In your case, `$db_con` can be not defined, or it is in a different scope.

Try to use

```
global $db_con;
```

In line `11` of `create_aviso.php`